# drawer menu with checkbox hack, with links to anchor on same page

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I have made a drawer menu for my website, using the checkbox hack. More specifically, I've based 99% of the code on this tutorial: http://www.designcouch.com/home/why/2014/04/23/pure-css-drawer-menu/

Everything is working like a charm except for one little thing. one of the links in my drawer links to a division a bit more towards the bottom of the index page. Since I'm using a hero image, I want people to be able to use this link to go down to the div. Now the problem is, that when I click that link, the drawer stays open! So the checkbox doesn't uncheck. I guess this makes sense, since there wasn't a new page loaded.

I thought about using a little javascript, to uncheck the checkbox if the link is clicked, but wanted to listen here first if you guys have a better solution. Nothing against JS but It seems kind of silly to make a pure css drawer, that than still needs javascript to function properly :p 
Any ideas on how to solve this without javascript?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds great. Was there a question here somewhere?

Comment: What happens if you put a label inside your link, referring to the checkbox?

Comment: If I put a label inside of the link, then the checkbox gets unchecked but link doesn't work anymore. If I put the link inside of the label, then the checkbox doesn't get unchecked

Answer (score 1):

So this was almost 4 years ago but I ran into the same issue the other day and after a lot of frustration, I came to StackOverflow looking for the light at the end of the tunnel... but there was none... until now

Anyway, I found a decent way to achieve what is being asked.
Instead of toggling the menu with a checkbox I've toggled it once the label was focused, so:

```
label.mobile-menu-toggle:focus + aside {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Once a user clicks on a link it scrolls down the page, and since the focus has been removed from the label the mobile menu slides back to where it belongs.